# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed> in phishing website detection

Tags: phishing

In phishing website detection using machine learning. In the step of extracting the features and storing them in the list. it gives error

> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

How to rectify the error and what is the cause of the error?

[image]

[image]

I tried dns resolver and all the possibilities to rectify the error

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or errors, copy the original text to your question instead. And use relevant tags in your question.

Comment: "getaddrinfo failed" means the host name could not be resolved into an IP address, via the used DNS service. _"I tried dns resolver and all the possibilities to rectify the error"_ - maybe it _can't_ be rectified, because the host name you are trying to make a request to, doesn't exist (any more)? Can't tell from your screenshot, because I don't see any actual request URL anywhere, but _if_ that is the case you are dealing with - then you should probably simply try to catch the error, and move on to the next URL to test.